# What do we need to consider if we're to receive a large cash gift from family abroad?

Tags: united-states, taxes, international, gifts

Are there any rules regarding receiving monetary gifts from family abroad? My fiance's parents want to wire us $25,000 from Brazil to be used on a down payment on a house.  What are the tax or other implications?

Comment: I did some research and I think I found the answer at the IRS. Here https://origin.bankrate.com/brm/itax/tax_adviser/20060823a1.asp and www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/i3520.pdf Essentially, for a gift from a family member there is a reporting threshold of $100,000. Meaning, if you recieve less than $100,000 gift from family abroad, you don't have to report it.

Comment: Submit an answer and accept it.  I think you are right =).  The relatives in Brazil might have some issues with taxes, but you shouldn't.

Comment: I think mortgage lenders are particular about gifts being used for down payments.   If you want to use it for a down payment, I would talk to a mortgage lender and ask how to do it.  Sometimes they want a letter stating it is a "gift" and not a "loan", etc.

Comment: @AlexB How do they know it wasn't simply "savings" if the mortgagee doesn't bring it up?  Not questioning your advice, I'm simply asking about the practices regarding such a requirement.

Comment: @Renesis If they look at your past bank statements and see a large deposit, they can ask about it.   It's happened to a few people I know.

Answer (score 2):

From the OP in a comment:

> I did some research and I think I found the answer at the IRS. Here
>   http://origin.bankrate.com/brm/itax/tax_adviser/20060823a1.asp and
>   http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/i3520.pdf Essentially, for a gift from a
>   family member there is a reporting threshold of $100,000. Meaning, if
>   you receive less than $100,000 gift from family abroad, you don't have
>   to report  it. – user1966 Sep 11 at 3:01

Answer (score 0):

I would create documentation for the gift by having the giver write a short note. That way, if the IRS questions a large transfer to you, you can show that it is a "gift" and not "income."

If the GIVER were in the U.S. the gift would be limited to something like $11,000 per year, ($22,000 per couple), per recipient. The giver would have to report and pay a "gift tax" on anything above that.

But one giving couple can give a total of $44,000 a year to one receiving couple ($22,000 per recipient).